# Start application on windows startup / boot but allow it visible to users when logged in?

Tags: windows, authentication, startup

I've tried using Scheduled Tasks using "Run whether user is logged on or not", but it appears to run the application in a separate instance even if its started when the user is logged in already.

Is there a way to do this programatically? Does windows allow this at all or will I need to stop the program(s) and restart them under the user credentials?

Comment: Can you please explain little more clear?

Comment: I'm trying to start applications at windows startup / boot, and allow any (or specific if thats the only way) users to be able to see them when they log in. If you use task scheduler to do it the programs even if run using the user credentials are run separate from the regular windows UI. You can see them running under the user's credentials but they can't interact with them (invisible)

Comment: @ArunRaj did that help clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the tasks are launched as background tasks so the user cannot access them.

You should launch cmd.exe via "the Sheduled Tasks" and launch your application through cmd (passing it by parameters).

see : [How to launch cmd.exe to execute command using Task Scheduler ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507707/how-to-launch-cmd-exe-to-execute-command-using-task-scheduler)