# How to launch cmd.exe to execute command using Task Scheduler ?

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks

I want to launch **cmd.exe** to execute command using **Task Scheduler** :

Here is my command line :

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -f "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\index.php"`

This command will load a **php.exe** and run my **php** script from `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php`

Here is how I set up my task scheduler :

[image]

I am not sure - what to put in the Start in Box - plus since it's (optional) so I leave it blank.

After save the task and hit run, I got this

[image]

It doesn't do anything.

What did I do wrong - here ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Program should not be `cmd` but `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe` and the argument should be `-f "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\index.php"`. You can leave `Start in` blank. It refers to "current folder" from the program's perspective. It should not really matter in you current scenario.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean, but if I want to stick in my way, there is  no way - it will work right ! I'm just curious - your suggestion is 100% working.

Comment: Sure, it would be `cmd.exe` in program, but then arguments would be: `/C "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -f C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\index.php"`.

Comment: It's an argument switch for `cmd`. Type `help cmd` in a command prompt to see the arguments that you can use with `cmd.exe`.