# Implement an automatic reminder email feature for web based application like in yii application by using cron jobs

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cron, jobs

We are running a yii apllication. I want to send reminder email to all those registered on my site 3 days before the event.

The registrant details are in my MySQL and it is a yii PHP website.

How do I do that?

Can any one tell me briefly it is importent

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please see similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40522990/2333476

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To add remainder email in yii using crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522990/to-add-remainder-email-in-yii-using-crontab)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write Cron job for that. For writing, you follow below steps
1. Include cronRun.php file with the command to run 
2. inside protected folder write mail sending function inside commands folder
  for ex:
`class PendingMailCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
     public function actionIndex() { 
     ....... //Mail sending code, database query code 
     }
     }`

3. set command in cron job in your server