# How to launch cmd.exe to execute DTExec using Task Scheduler?

Tags: sql-server, cmd, ssis, windows-task-scheduler, dtexec

I'm trying to automate a SSIS package using `dtexec` via Task Scheduler (as I do not have rights to create it via SQL Agent) and need it done locally on my machine.  I referenced this post:  [How to launch cmd.exe to execute command using Task Scheduler ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507707/how-to-launch-cmd-exe-to-execute-command-using-task-scheduler), but I can't get the syntax right for dtexec.

My Program Script is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe"
```

with Add Argument of:

```
/f “C:\Users\f9a\Desktop/HRFact.dtsx”
```

[image]

But when it runs, it pops up the `cmd` window for a split second, then goes away.  The History shows a return code of 4.

[image]

I can run this in `cmd.exe` by typing this:

```
dtexec/f “C:\Users\f9a\Desktop/HRFact.dtsx”
```

and it works fine. I just can't seem to get the syntax for Task Scheduler.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `Start In` textbox value to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\
```

And change `Program/Script` textbox value to

```
DtExec
```

**Useful links**

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx
- [How to schedule a SSIS package job in SQL sheduler or Windows scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079616/how-to-schedule-a-ssis-package-job-in-sql-sheduler-or-windows-scheduler)
- http://www.microsoft-sql-ssis.com/2015/09/running-ssis-package-from-command.html
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eb800310-bfb4-4caf-ad8e-f3f9c36ff885/running-the-ssis-package-using-the-task-scheduler?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: That didn't do anything different.  Still has cmd window pop up for a split second then close with no results.  Any other ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(This should probably be a comment, but is a bit long for that. Sorry.)

Your task seems to work correctly. That you only see the console window pop up quickly is because `DTEXEC` starts (it is a console application after all), but exits immediately with an error.

The return code 4, which is the exit code (or `ERRORLEVEL`) `DTEXEC` returns, when it cannot find the package file (according to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx)).

Since the package seems to be located in the directory of a particular user (`“C:\Users\f9a\Desktop/HRFact.dtsx”`), make sure that the user that runs the task has access to this directory.

(Also for sanity, consider using a backslash before the filename, albeit that shouldn't matter)

Comment: Thanks, @Christian.K, but I am the user f9a, and can run it locally through the DtExecGUI and it works - I just can't seem to get the syntax right for Windows Task Scheduler.